# lower central series $ [G^2 , G^3]\leq G^5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G^i$ be a lower central series.
I want to prove $[G^2 , G^3]\leq G^5$ without using Three subgroup lemma.

Comment: "a" ...lower central series, or "the" lower central series? Both lower and upper central series are "the" series.